# Adminer cannot find PHP extensions

Tags: php, mysql, windows, apache, adminer

5.2.17, apache 2.2.5 and MySQL 5.6.22 and adminer 4.1.0-mysql

My configuration

```
**[SYSTEM variables]**

PHPRC = C:\PHP

PATH = ....;C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\bin\;C:\PHP;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5.3 & MySQL Utilities 1.5.3 1.5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5.3 & MySQL Utilities 1.5.3 1.5\Doctrine extensions for PHP\

**[SYSTEM variables]**


**[PHP.ini]**
extension_dir = "C:\PHP\ext"
extension=php_mysql.dll
**[PHP.ini]**

**[httpd.conf]**
LoadModule php5_module "C:/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll"

AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
PHPIniDir "C:\PHP\"
**[httpd.conf]**
```

but when I go to adminer I authenticate I get this message in Adminer

**Error** None of the supported PHP extensions (MySQLi, MySQL, PDO_MySQL) are available. **Error**

but I ve tried everything but I was not able to locate error. It s weird. Is somebody here who have similar problem and figure out.

libmysql.dll is in system32 folder I really dont know what is the problem here

When I query Mysql it works so its very weird behavior.

Thanks Jakub

Comment: I've fixed it with PHP 5.3.29 its weird because on different computer this configuration works. Hope it help somebody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Linux please check extension loaded folder(if there is mysqli.ini/mysqlnd.ini in /etc/php/../apache2/mods-available ) file available or not in configuration loaded folder.Even i use command apt-get install php-mysql sometimes library file are missing.

For Windows check library folder and check if required library file is present or not.